# iPhone X - Temperature Problem

Tags: iphone, temperature

I believe I may have a temperature problem with my iPhone X. My iPhone gets extremely warm when using Snapchat. Even up to 92 degrees Fahrenheit! Snapchat is not the only app that causes this behavior. Safari and Facebook both cause similar warmth. Texting and phone calls can also increase the temp but not as much (only up to 84 degrees).

It generally idles a degree or two more then room temp and during charging it can warm up to [ missing temp ] even when not in use.

To troubleshoot, I have attempted to reset. Unfortunately, this did not fix this issue.

Also don't believe its a hardware issue as this my second X, and also happens on my spare iPhone 7....

If any of you have a thermometer to check the temp that would be awesome.

Thank you.

Comment: Any ideas anybody? Just trying to see if this is normal...

Answer (score 2):

92 degrees F is not an issue. Snapchat and similar programs that use the camera, GPS, and have higher GPU/CPU requirements will cause the phone to get warmer. If it was 92C then that wouldn't be good, but 92F just means you're using a lot of battery power.

Answer (score 1):

Yah, the processors in these things are highly capable and can put out a lot of heat. If it becomes uncomfortable, try looking at your environment. Switch to a less constrictive protective case. This can help for a number a reasons. Some cases can impede cellular and wifi strength and cause the device to work harder to maintain a connection. Some cases can also be thermally restrictive and don't dissipate heat very well. See if you continue to have issues if you go case-less. The iPhone has a ton of safety sensors and will automatically shut down if it becomes too hot, so you don't have anything to worry about: https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201678

Apple also provides the following info from https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201678 :

**Your device might get warm**

When you use the device or charge the battery, the device might get warm. You might notice that your device feels warmer in these situations:

- When you set up your device the first time
- When you restore from a backup
- When apps reindex or reanalyze data, like Photos tagging for faces, places, or keywords after a software update
- When you use graphics-intensive or augmented-reality apps or features

These conditions are normal, and your device will return to a regular temperature when complete.

Here are some of the higher ambient-temperature conditions and activities that might cause the device to change performance and behavior:

- Leaving the device in a car on a hot day.
- Leaving the device in direct sunlight for an extended period of time.
- Using certain features in hot conditions or direct sunlight for an extended period of time, such as GPS tracking or navigation in a car, playing a graphics-intensive game, or using augmented-reality apps.